# How can I get my supervisor to recap discussions via email instead of in person despite reaching out and asking for communication in that way?

Tags: professionalism

I’ve had to address a few concerns with HR and my manager regarding possible discrimination and unethical practices. My initial contact was made via email, and meetings were had almost immediately.

At the conclusion of meetings, I email, thanking them for meeting with me and ask that they send a recap of issues addressed and the explanations/solutions they provided, but they will only call or ask me to come to the office to address... Not leaving any form of concrete evidence of such matters. What steps can I take to get this to happen?

Comment: If these are formal meetings why is no-one taking minutes?  It's been said that without minutes from a meeting there was no meeting  - or at least no decisions worthy of action being made.

Comment: Hi, generic reminder about engaging with HR: "HR is not your friend" (they work for their employer) https://www.inc-aus.com/jt-odonnell/what-20-somethings-need-to-know-about-complaining-to-hr.html

Comment: Re *"come to the office to address"*: Address what? Something seems to be missing.

Comment: Any chance you could write up YOUR notes from the meeting, email them and ask them for any corrections?

Comment: You can’t. It sounds like for whatever reason they don’t want an electronic paper trail and ate acting to avoid it.

Comment: @bob Of course the OP could.  It does put the other people in an awkward spot, and maybe there's a reason to not do it.  But waiting for the other people to commit to writing sounds like a lost cause.

Comment: @DaveG I agree with your comment. I just meant that trying to force *them* to do the write up won’t work, as you said.

Answer (score 150):

If you want an e-mail trail, which is understandable, you should summarize the meeting and send that summary to the supervisor, asking whether there is anything they would have worded differently. If they choose not to respond, your presentation of the meeting results is obviously correct :-) If they request or suggest a change, whether orally or in writing, you may re-word your summary and go through the process again.

You can't force your manager to write down meeting notes, but they can't really prevent you from doing it.

Comment: I agree with this answer in principle and was about to write something similar. But at least in the context of the US legal system saying "your presentation of the meeting results is obviously correct" is probably going too far. There are definitely ways to explain a failure to respond that do not imply endorsement. Still, it does create real evidence of what was said and if the other side wants to dispute it, it does put the onus on them to explain both what was incorrect and why they didn't correct the record. This is the right way to go, it just isn't absolute.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman - note the smiley after "obviously correct"

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: If they don't correct you, that doesn't _prove_ that what you wrote is correct. However, what it does do is provide a _reasonable basis_ for you to then act on the assumption that it is indeed correct. If at a later time, the supervisor claims that OP did something completely wrong, OP can point at the email and respond that they were working based off of the meeting notes that were sent to the supervisor ages ago which they did not provide a correct for.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman: In other words, when facing scrutiny for your actions, the legal system is less about what is provably correct, and more about what you had good reason to believe was correct. If your belief was not unreasonable, then your behavior was not out of line (obviously restricted to reasonable meeting minutes in the first place)

Comment: This is the solution I would have proposed, and I have used this in the past. However, I've found it usual that I simply get no replies to such e-mail messages, and they appear to be ignored. Depending on the situation, you _may_ want to bring up the lack of a reply in your next face-to-face meeting to try to force a response (whether it be, "you're wrong," or "I accept that"). This additional pressure can also backfire, simply making the counterparty more annoyed and less likely to deal with the situation in a way beneficial to you. You'll have to make a judgement call for your situation.

Answer (score 21):

You can't dictate to your boss how they communicate. However I would agree that when you are talking about ethical and discrimination practices, not getting a written record is a red flag (meaning a warning that something is not right). Your boss can say something and then deny that they said it later. Usually I would expect there to be written communication.

There's a couple of things you can try. First, take explicit notes in the meetings yourself. Openly write down everything that is said as it is said. If anything isn't clear read what you have written back and check it is accurate. Don't worry if this makes the meeting go slower - you are entitled to have accurate records in circumstances like this. Make sure you phrase this as "I want to make sure I'm remembering everything that is said" not "I want an accurate record for my lawyer", even if the latter is true. If possible, or if the boss objects to the time taken, ask if you can audio record the meetings instead. I would expect some pushback on this. Bosses don't like to have every little thing they say recorded, especially if they want to be able to deny some things later. Under no circumstances attempt to record meetings without their permission.

As well as this (and even more so if your boss doesn't allow you to take notes at your own pace) write yourself a written summary of what was said, send it to your boss, and tell them to get back to you if anything you wrote was inaccurate. If they don't reply ask them specifically at your next meeting if your summary was accurate.

Assuming HR is involved (and HR should always be involved in discussions like this) also send your summary of the meeting to HR. If there is no HR, send it to your boss' boss, or someone else in the company who has some authority.

The point of this is a) when your boss denies he promised you something, you have the email where you told him that you thought he had promised it, and he didn't correct you (and hopefully even agreed in writing). Copying HR will also flag things for their attention if you boss promises something that can't be delivered.

By aware that these are somewhat confrontational. You can and should use them in cases like this, but not in everyday interactions with your boss.

Comment: "not getting a written record is a red flag." It's not a red flag. It's standard procedure for any HR of any company. HR's role is to protect the company first and foremost.

Comment: It means that HR/boss don't want to be held accountable. So in that sense it's a red flag, even if it's also standard procedure. Something can be both "very bad for the employee" and "standard procedure".

Comment: It can mean that. It also could be the supervisor is unaware that’s how it can be perceived by outsiders.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I guess we both have a different definition of what "red flag" means. To me, a "red flag" means that you shouldn't be working at such a company. Unfortunately, this "red flag" behavior is so common, it would eliminate 99% of the jobs out there.

Comment: Yes, there's two ways "red flag" is used. One is that a warning sign that something is not right. The other is that it's a deal breaker, and you should get out at all costs. I mean the first. (Please don't anybody use comments to tell me that you think it should be the other way.)

Comment: Absolutely second the suggestion to take minutes and ask the manager to confirm their accuracy. Heck, this can be a useful service for the whole department, if your manager doesn't want next to your sharing them around. I've played that role (though my notes tend to be detailed enough that folks have accused me of taking seconds rather than minutes)

Comment: @Stephan You seem to have been working for a whole lot of pretty awful companies, because this is certainly not standard in my experience. If the only way HR can "protect the company" is to ensure there is no papertrail something is _horribly_ wrong (and almost certainly going to achieve the opposite of protecting the company in the medium to long term).

Comment: By the way, the dictionary agrees that "red flag" means a warning, not a deal breaker.

Comment: @DJClayworth, unfortunately, dictionaries aren't the true definition of words, common usage is. Dictionaries are truly only a description of common use, so it lags behind what people are using a word to mean. If you think this is untrue, look at the word "literally" as it no longer only means "literally", but also "figuratively" or "virtually". Also, in common use, red flags are used to mean the step causing the end of a process. In car racing, they may "red flag" a race (meaning to stop the race), then see if they can get it restarted by fixing whatever stopped the race.

Comment: @computercarguy I can give you no end of sites, not just dictionaries giving the "warning" meaning. I'm very aware of the alternative usage - I actually mentioned it above. I'm extremely aware of the usage of "literally". Just trying to make sure people don't "correct" me when I use the real definition instead of the alternative one.

Answer (score 5):

Always remember HR is a last resort. Lower your expectations to the ground. They are not on your side. They exist to protect the company from problem employees, and no matter which employee is the perpetrator and which is the victim, both are considered problem employees.

The perp is a problem because they make employees complain about them and consume company time dealing with it.

The victim is a problem because they can't suck it up and instead complain and consume company time dealing with it.

From the company's point of view, the *actual* problem is that company time has been consumed without producing product.

At some point in time, someone mistakenly thought HR stood for "Human Relations" and that mistake frequently gets repeated. But, no, it stands for "Human Resources". You are one of the company's resources, just like iron is a resource in a foundry. That's all you are to HR—except unlike iron, you might get uppity when someone beats you down.

Also, we're keen to say HR protects the company first, but the real truth is that HR protects *HR* first, which is why it's hard to get a paper trail from them. The company comes *second*, and you ... *miiight* be on the list somewhere, if they feel like they can't fire you without hurting the bottom line—at least not too much—or creating a legal liability risk.

If you want a paper trail (or an e-trail), you have to make it yourself. State in writing what happened during the meeting in terms that clearly state what you heard and therefore expect from the company going forward, e.g. "Thank you for addressing my concerns in the meeting we just had. I was glad to hear that Pat is no longer allowed to light campfires in the office." CC everyone present at the meeting and print it out for your own records.

Comment: I know that this sentiment about HR is very common, especially here and in other social media; and it is of course easy and safe to use this in advice. There are *definitely* companies out there where HR is not the enemy of humans, and where HR knows that the people in the company are, in fact, more important than some wasted hours.  -1 for using 4x the space on the usual "HR bad" line (compared to a final paragraph with the actual advice) which is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @AnoE - Yes, there are of course exceptions to the rule, but they should be treated as such. Expect the worst and be happy if you find something better. It's just safer that way. And, to be fair, it doesn't usually take very long to figure out which kind of HR you have, so starting out wary doesn't mean you have to stay wary for very long if you get a kind/sensible HR rep. I just always remember an HR person who told me that because I had vacation days scheduled for the same time two days the office was closed due to inclement weather, I had therefore used up those two vacation days. 

Comment: @AnoE Actually, now that I read your comment again, I realize you're being abrasive. I come to SE to seek & share wisdom. If I share more than was asked, I don't think that's a problem. People need to know about HR. If I can warn them in passing while talking about their specific case, that's a good thing. People can lose their job, ruin their reputation, or end their career by dealing with a malignant HR department unknowingly. I'm not going to be miserly with my wisdom, which was hard-won in similar situations, just because you think I spoke too long. Yours was not a helpful comment.

Comment: The comment is not intended to be overly abrasive. I'm in the habit of commenting whenever I downvote. If it came over annoying, then it could just be me typing fast inbetween doing other stuff. That said, this is how SE should work IMO - people vote based on many aspects, not the least their opinion (especially in "soft" areas like Workplace). You are free to do with the comments whatever you please, including ignoring them. ;) (In this case, my issue ist mostly the relative length given to the different topics - the "HR issue" could be done with a single short sentence IMO).

Comment: @AnoE Sometimes the answer to a question is to tell the person they're asking the wrong question, e.g. a woman asks how to cover up the black eyes her husband gave her; the advice she wants is the not the advice she actually needs.

Comment: we can go back and forth ad nauseam; I just wanted to give feedback. I am very happy to agree to disagree. I have read the question again, and still I see no hint whatsoever that OP has a conflict with HR or his manager, he is simply trying to get a paper trail. The currently by far top-voted question explains that perfectly with zero risk of exposing OP themselves to anything untoward.

Answer (score 0):

You won't.

If someone, despite multiple requests, continues to communicate only verbally and not in writing, they have a good reason for doing that, and they have already clearly shown you that they are unwilling to put anything in writing.

Especially if these are HR people or supervisors, this is almost certainly an intentional move on their part.

What you can do, as a weak replacement, is to send them an e-mail yourself summarizing the points. Don't ask them to confirm - if they avoid writing as obviously as they seem to do, they won't do that. Instead, at the end of the mail ask them an innocent, unrelated question. Such as confirming the follow-up meeting date or asking for one, or something else. You want them to respond to that, which at least gives you a small proof that you actually sent and they actually received and read your mail. This is probably the best you can get. If they're responding to **that** by calling you, then you need to start writing a diary or logbook, because something serious is up.